# Detect the first rising edge of 3 input signals

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, flipflop, synthesis

I have 3 input signals which are pulse waveforms The output is switch to high once once  all 3 first rising edges of 3 inputs are detected. 
Is there a digital circuit from logic gates, flip flop that can do that? 
I am thinking about flip flop but the problem is that it detects with every rising edge not just the first rising edge.

[image]

Comment: And when does out go low?

Comment: You need a combination of Flip-Flops and logic gates.

Comment: Are you trying to detect if y and z go high before the second rising edge on x? Or, if they went high after the second rising edge, would that also result in the output going high?

Comment: @Tyler it will remain high from that time

Comment: @Annie: no, the order doesn't matter, only detect the first rising edges of 3 inputs. After the first rising edges of 3 inputs are detected, the output goes high and remains at that value

Comment: `flip flop detects with every rising edge` ... that is not quite true .... the word `detects` should be the word `latches` instead ... and you are talking about a clock input .... think what would happen to the output if the data input is tied high

Comment: Can't you just measure the output? Or do you need to switch the output on yourself? If so a simple 3-AND gate and a latch will work... But you will need to reset it also.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use the circuit below with 3 D flip-flops and one 3-input AND gate.
You would also need to use the reset input of the flip-flops to bring the output back to zero (not indicated in the schematic).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJRddE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You can move the FF after the 3-input AND to save 2 FFs.

Comment: @Paebbels - To use your proposal we need the two first (sequentially speaking) inputs to be high at the rising edge of the last input, what is not the case in the example given. Notice that X is already low when Y goes high.

Comment: I accept you arguments, but the drawing is way to inaccurate to say `X` is definitely down :).

Answer (score 6):

Put each input on the set of an SR latch, and AND all the outputs together.

Answer (score 2):

As defined 3 rising edges are asynchronous thus reset 3 latches and 
NOR input= output